# Most efficient way to get coroutine handle from within a C++ coroutine

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-coroutine

I'm fairly new to C++ coroutines.  When my app shuts down, I'd like to be able to give any outstanding co-routines a hint that I'd prefer they finished early.  One solution/idea I came up with was to put a bool on the promise, and then I need a way to check the bool from within the co-routine.

I pieced together a fairly simple solution (using co_await to get the handle), but this feels like a kluge -- the compiler ought to already have access to the handle from within the frame.  I'm wondering if there is a standard intrinsic that allows access to the handle or the promise?  Or if anyone has come up with a cleaner, better solution?

```
struct co_gethandle_awaitable
{
    co_gethandle_awaitable()
        : m_hWaiter(nullptr)
    {
    }
    bool await_ready() const noexcept
    {
        return m_hWaiter != nullptr;
    }
    void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<> hWaiter) noexcept
    {
        m_hWaiter = hWaiter;
        m_hWaiter.resume();
    }
    void await_resume() noexcept
    {
    }

    std::coroutine_handle<> m_hWaiter;
};

coroutine_ref<void> MyFunc()
{
    // get my coroutine handle.  Ideally this would be a helper function
    // but then it would have to be awaitable, which would add further cost.
    co_gethandle_awaitable obj;
    co_await obj;
    std::coroutine_handle<> hMe = obj.m_hWaiter;

    // loop.
    {
        // do work.

        if (is_cancelled(hMe))
          break;
    }

    co_return;
}
```

Comment: Almost there. Use `bool await_suspend(hWaiter) { m_hWaiter = hWaiter; return false; } auto await_resume() { return m_hWaiter; }`. That way, the coroutine resumes immediately (without reentrancy, which `m_hWaiter.resume();` would create), and the return value of the `co_await` is the coroutine handle. Caller would be `auto my_handle = co_await co_gethandle_awaitable();` The more conventional way is for the `coroutine_ref<void>` to use `await_transform` so coroutines can say `while (!co_await co_is_cancelled())`.